# Creates x dates from now

Tags: javascript

I want to create an array of x dates from now.
So today is 28 Jul and the result should be:

```js
const result = ['28 Jul', '29 Jul', '30 Jul', '31 Jul', '1 Aug', '2 Aug', '3 Aug']
```

This is my code:

```js
const today = new Date();
const dates = Array.from(Array(7).keys()).map((i) =>
  new Date(today.setDate(today.getDate() + i)).toLocaleString('en-EN', {
    day: '2-digit',
    month: '2-digit',
    year: 'numeric',
  }),
);
console.log('dates: ', dates);
```

The result is:

```
[
  "07/28/2021",
  "07/29/2021",
  "07/31/2021",
  "08/03/2021",
  "08/07/2021",
  "08/12/2021",
  "08/18/2021"
]
```

Dates are not consecutive. Why?

I prefer not to use any library like Moment and co

Comment: Simple, you wote the program so that they're not. Remove the call to `today.setDate`.

Comment: Notice the pattern: consecutive, 1 day skipped, 2 days skipped, 3 days skipped... What might be going wrong here? :)

Comment: Keep `today.setDate`, you need that, but instead of `new Date` just do `today.setDate(today.getDate()+1)` and then `toLocaleString` that.

Comment: Every time you call `today.setDate` you mutate the date. `today` isn't read only. Your altering it on every call.

Comment: You can also simplify your use of `Array.from()` which gives you an implicit `map()` call as its second argument. `const dates = Array.from({ length: 7 }, (_, i) => new Date(...));`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your problem is related to the fact that you are changing `today` in `map`.

To solve this, you could use a function `addDays` in which you pass the date and the days you want to add in this way:

```js
function addDays(date, days) {
  var result = new Date(date);
  result. setDate(result. getDate() + days);
  return result;
}

const today = new Date();
const dates = Array.from(Array(7).keys()).map((i) =>
  addDays(today, i).toLocaleString('en-EN', {
    day: '2-digit',
    month: '2-digit',
    year: 'numeric',
  })
);
console.log('dates: ', dates);
```